# Loading Contents before Displaying in HTML5

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, load

I am developing a magazine in the internet and I want to know if it is possible to load all contents (images,videos,DOM) into a ready state before actually displaying the contents. While loading, a progress bar will show the progress of the content loading. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Have something like:

```
<body>
     <div id="allcontent" style="display:none;"> 
          <!-- your entire page -->
     </div>
     <div id="progressbar">...</div>
</body>
```

And then

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#progressbar').remove();
    $('#allcontent').show();
});
```

**EDIT**: you could simulate the progress by counting the number of `$('img')` and then calculating the percentage of already loaded images at each `$('img').load` event. It's not perfect, but better than nothing

Comment: this will make the content not accessible at all when javascript is not available

Comment: then hide it on `$(document).ready`, instead of in the HTML. (Will it flicker?)

Comment: And thats exactly what @AJ Naidas wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a solution boilerplate-like, using a specific class applied to `<html>` element. See my example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tKtYd/

the idea is to apply the class `waitpageloadbeforedisplay` via javascript soon in the `head` and then use this class in the CSS to hide the main site wrapper. Then just wait for the window `load` event to remove that class and show your site content. In this way the content is still accessible, even if javascript is not available/disabled.

The loader is shown as a body background, using the css rule `.waitpageloadbeforedisplay body`(so you don't need to use markup for styling purpose).